# How to get the maximum value of a vector layer without filters?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to get a maximum value of a field in a vector layer without using the filter that is active in QGIS. So far I've tried:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('fid')
print layer.maximumValue(idx)
```

This sends the following SQL query to my SQL Server database (I have filtered the layer by fid in QGIS):

```
select max([fid]) from [mySchema].[myLayer] where ("fid" < 1000)
```

Is it possible to send

```
select max([fid]) from [mySchema].[myLayer]
```

instead? I'd still like to have the filter on, so that not all features are shown on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may temporary disable your filter to get the wanted info and restore it just after like below sample

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('fid')

# Save your layer filter to a variable
save_substr = layer.subsetString()

# Remove your filter to be sure to do calculation on all records
layer.setSubsetString('')

# Make your calculation without the filter
print(layer.maximumValue(idx))

# Restore your filter
layer.setSubsetString(save_substr)
```

Comment: This worked for me when the layer was not currently in edit mode. However, if the layer is being edited, the maximum value is still calculated from the filtered features.